# I'm looking for a download manager that can send an HTTP head request before download

Tags: linux, debian

Can anybody name a good download manager (like IDM in Windows) that can send an HTTP head request and show the file name and size before downloading the file? Every single download manager that I installed does not have such a basic feature. I have tried uGet, Persepolis, etc.

Comment: `man wget` `man aria2c` `man curl`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov These are command line utilities. I'm looking for a download manager with GUI.

Comment: Wine + your favourite Windows DL manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on Ubuntu, persepolis shows the file size beforehand.